# PHP | curl multi | timeout | connect_timeout | check for 200 | debugging

Tags: php, curl

I got a curl multi going like the pasted code at bottom.

The problem is that, nearly randomly, the result array differs and i want to know why.

i think it is related to the default SETOPT timeout or connect_timeout which more after is related to the websites loading time (which is random).

setting a custom CURLOPT_TIMEOUT of 20 decreases my result array by 60%. Does that mean most valuable requests takes more than 20 seconds?

Would it be an option to check the header with curl first and if 200 (OK) than process??
Are my settings optimal?

```
$ch = curl_multi_init();
foreach ($links_2 as $count => $link)
{
        $curl_array[$count] = curl_init($link);
        curl_setopt($curl_array[$count], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl_array[$count], CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($curl_array[$count], CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);    
        curl_multi_add_handle($ch, $curl_array[$count]);
}

do {
    curl_multi_exec($ch, $exec);
} while($exec > 0);

foreach($links_2 as $count => $link) 
{
        $returned = curl_multi_getcontent($curl_array[$count]);
        $pattern_email = '/[A-Z0-9._%+-]+(@|\(at\)|\[at\])[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i'; 
        preg_match_all($pattern_email,$returned,$emails);
        foreach ($emails[0] as $m)
        {
            $email_all[] = $m;
        }

}



foreach($links_2 as $count => $link)  
{
        curl_multi_remove_handle($ch, $curl_array[$count]);
}

curl_multi_close($ch); 

foreach($links_2 as $count => $link) 
{
        curl_close($curl_array[$count]);
}
```

btw, this is NOT a webcrawler, we use it intern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a combination of the random loading time of the website to be crawled and also the own current server capacity.